# NSExtensionContext openURL not working from OS X Today extension

Tags: cocoa, today-extension

I want to call my app on my OSX Today Extension.
This is the code that I'm using for testing:

```
NSURL *appURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];    
NSAssert(self.extensionContext != nil, @"extension context is nil");
[self.extensionContext openURL:appURL completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    NSLog(@"opened successfully: %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");

}];
```

Its being called when the user triggers thte double action of a NSTableView.
I was not sure If I was using the URL for my app correctly, so I set it to google for testing.
The thing is that the completion handler is not being called, so I'm guessing somehting is blocking it.

Do I need to specify something in the sandbox capabilities for this to work, or anything else I should check ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSExtensionContext openURL not working on Mac OS X Today Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446320/nsextensioncontext-openurl-not-working-on-mac-os-x-today-widget)